# posting to another server from controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i have a form in my MVC website where it posts data to a third party website where the user will leave my website and continue on the other server with the data sent in my post.

the problem is that the data must be processed and encrypted before being sent in which i do it in the code behind before sending it, i couldn't find a way to create the request from the code behind so i made an ajax call from the view to post the form to the controller where i encrypt it the send an json object back to the view where i fill a hidden form then post this form's data to the third party website.

so is there a way to make this post request from the controller directly?

if not is there a way that is better than i did ?

Comment: i am posting the encrypted data to a third party website not to anther controller on my website

Comment: Please don't update your question by adding comments, instead, click the edit button and update your question.

Comment: @ErikPhilips i have edited my post, and no that's not a duplicate as the other only wants a response from his request, i want to redirect the user to the third party website using this post request

Comment: "Better" is subject to _your_ needs/requirements. An "alternative" is changing "when" you would POST to 3rd party (without XHR) - which is subjective/based on whatever UI/flow you want. It's assumed that you're validating (validation token? model validation?) the XHR (re: checking/validating what you're ultimately processing/encrypting and subsequently sending somewhere).

Comment: @EdSF i am using model validation in code behind then send a json object with the values to be posted back to the form and posting it using form.submit();

Comment: Did you find any solution? I'm also in the same place